# &copy; and &trade; symbols are not appearing correctly

Tags: angularjs, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am having trouble with Chrome and IE in getting to display the following characters

©
™

They are rendered as diamond with question mark in Chrome and as a smartphone like icon in IE.

My primary page has this already:

What is causing the issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: do you have the page encoding set correctly?

Comment: you forgot the code but it's a charset issue, check in your ide or in your html

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the `charset` of your html file to `UTF-8`.